# Delete saved password for StackExchange

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, stack-exchange-openid, password

I've changed my password for SE and am trying to learn it. So I want to be logged out of SE when I close my browser or turn off the computer or similar, so that I learn the password by typing it lots. But when I log out and try to log back in, it logs me straight in without asking me for a password. Don't get me wrong, any other time that's a useful feature, but is there a way I can disable it, and a setting I can change so that I have to relog every time I leave my browser, or similar? I'm using Chrome, I cleared out the saved passwords and unticked "Offer to save your web passwords" in Chrome settings, but my password is still saved for SE.

I don't know enough about scripts to use a programmatic solution, so if there is no way I can do this through either site settings or Chrome settings, I'll grin and bear it.

Comment: Clear local storage, that should cause you to need to retype the password.